# How to sandBox db file in windows store app

Tags: sqlite, windows-store-apps, sandbox

i m currently developing a windows store app for surface.i use sqlite for database tasks.but the db file saves in APPData folder as separate file.i want to make it more secure.how can i do that?if sandboxing is a solution,then how could i sandbox the db?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows Store apps run with (a limited set of) the user's permissions. Anything the app can get to the user can get to. Sandboxing prevents the app from affecting the rest of the system. It doesn't prevent the system (or the user) from getting to the app.

To secure the database from the user you'd need to keep it off-system on a site that you control.

On system you can make it more difficult for the user by encrypting the database or its contents. I haven't looked at it closely, but a quick search found that [SQLCipher Commercial Edition supports Windows Runtime apps](https://www.zetetic.net/blog/2014/1/13/introducing-sqlcipher-for-windows-phone-8-and-windows-runtim.html). If you prefer to encrypt it yourself take a look at the [Windows Runtime's data protection API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh465034.aspx).

Comment: Thanks @Rob. it will help.encryption might slow down the app.so can we store them in cloud?

Comment: You can store your data anywhere the client can reach. If the client has network access you can use a cloud hosted database which exposes its data via a web service. Azure Mobile Services is one way to do this (http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/mobile-services/ ), but anything exposed as a web service will do.